# how to implement a flutter aar in android native application

Tags: android, flutter, aar, flutter-add-to-app

I have a flutter application that I convert to module then generate a aar from it.
After that I get the configuration steps to implement it in a native android project, but after following the steps I get an error in AndroidManifest that say:
`Unresolved package 'flutter'`

```
<activity
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass" />
```

how can i resolve this issue?